# How to draw a graph with different sized nodes Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I calculated degree centrality for the nodes with the weight of the links between the nodes.
The next task is to draw a graph with nodes of different sizes. For example, if the degree centrality > 4, the node size = 1500, if < 4 = 500.
Help understand where the error is.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = [[0, 1.51, 0, 1.71, 0],
     [0, 0, 2.11, 1.81, 2.31],
     [0, 0, 0, 1.31, 1.41],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.matrix(A), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")


# a list of the node labels in the right order
raw_labels = ["A1", "K2", "D3", "E4", "Z30"]
lab_node = dict(zip(G.nodes, raw_labels))

print("Degree centrality weight")
d = G.degree(weight='weight')
print(d)

for x in d:
    if x[1] > 4:
        large = x
        print (large)
    else:
        small = x
        print (small)

nx.draw(G, layout)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout, edgelist=large, node_size=100)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout, edgelist=small, node_size=1500)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, layout, edge_labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, layout, labels=lab_node, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi,  Can you tell us what the expected outcome is and what is actually happening?

Comment: I suspect your code where you set `large=x` or `small=x` is doing something different from what you want.  At the end of the for loop, `large` will be the last value of `x` which was bigger than 4, and `small` will be the last value which is less than or equal to 4.  They will not be lists of the small or large values.  Each time you set them to equal something, they lose the previous value that was associated to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works. In your code were some issues: first like already Joel raised in the comments, you used `small` and `large` as variables, but wanted them to be list. Second, you have used `edgelist` instead of `nodelist` in [`draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html). 
I replaced the `nx.draw` with `nx.draw_networkx_edges` (and added `plt.axis("off")`) to allow other users drawing smaller or larger node sizes than the default size, because smaller sizes would not work with `nx.draw`.

As last personal recommendation, I would replace variable names, such as `d`, `G`, or `small`, with longer self explanatory names, like `node_degrees`, `graph`, `node_with_low_degrees`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = [[0, 1.51, 0, 1.71, 0],
     [0, 0, 2.11, 1.81, 2.31],
     [0, 0, 0, 1.31, 1.41],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.11],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(np.matrix(A), create_using=nx.DiGraph)

layout = nx.spring_layout(G)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "weight")


# a list of the node labels in the right order
raw_labels = ["A1", "K2", "D3", "E4", "Z30"]
lab_node = dict(zip(G.nodes, raw_labels))

print("Degree centrality weight")
d = G.degree(weight='weight')
print(d)

large = []
small = []
for node in G:
    if d[node] > 4: 
        large.append(node)
    else:
        small.append(node)

print("Small", small)
print("Large", large)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, layout)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout, nodelist=large, node_size=100)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, layout, nodelist=small, node_size=1500)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, layout, edge_labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, layout, labels=lab_node, font_size=10, font_family='sans-serif')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, it's worked! I have a question yet. Are there in Networkx functions for calculating "Closeness centrality" and "Betweenness" based on the weight of the edges?

Comment: See the documentation  you can specify `distance` for [`closeness_centrality`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality) and `weight` for [`betweenness_centrality`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality)